# Azure Devops CD pipeline drop create script

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

I want to create a CD release process targeting Azure SQL, but there is a mismatch between the database and the repo. I would like the CD pipeline to be based on the contents of the repo and the actual release to be based on that.

Replace DROP TABLE CREATE TABLE statement in sql scripts
Additional sqlpackage.exe arguments:
/p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True  /v:ProspectIDStartValue=1000000/ /p:AllowDropBlockingAssemblies=true /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=true /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false

Comment: What is the detailed problem you are facing currently in the release pipeline? And error messages returned in the release pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the release pipeline, if you want to directly the reference the source files from an Azure Git Repos, you can directly add that git repository as a source artifact.

By this way, you can specify which branch and comment will be checked out for use in the release pipeline.

[image]

---